# How do I read this network "frame" diagram?

Tags: websocket, packet, packets

Many times, such as on the website describing the WebSocket diagram [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/08/What-s-different-in-the-new-WebSocket-protocol?hl=en) I see "frame" diagrams (at least that is what I think they are called) like the following:

```
0                   1                   2                   3
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
 +-+-+-+-+-------+-+-------------+-------------------------------+
 |F|R|R|R| opcode|M| Payload len |    Extended payload length    |
 |I|S|S|S|  (4)  |A|     (7)     |             (16/63)           |
 |N|V|V|V|       |S|             |   (if payload len==126/127)   |
 | |1|2|3|       |K|             |                               |
 +-+-+-+-+-------+-+-------------+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
 |     Extended payload length continued, if payload len == 127  |
 + - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +-------------------------------+
 |                               |Masking-key, if MASK set to 1  |
 +-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
 | Masking-key (continued)       |          Payload Data         |
 +-------------------------------- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
 :                     Payload Data continued ...                :
 + - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
 |                     Payload Data continued ...                |
 +---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Can someone explain to me how to read such a diagram?  The way I interpret it would be that the `0 1 2 3` on the top would be the bytes that arrive in a packet, and the `0-9` repeating would be the individual bits. However this doesn't make sense as there are only 8 bits in a byte.

Further more:

- What are `fin` `rsv` `opcode` and `mask`?
- What exactly **is** the `Payload Data`.
- Is this entire frame one packet, or are there multiple frames in a packet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
0                   1                   2                   3
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
```

means

```
|    1st byte     |    2nd byte     |    3rd byte     |    4th byte     |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 | 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 | 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 |
| 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 | 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 | 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 | 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 |
```

That is, the table is 32-bit (= 4-byte) wide.

Descriptions about `fin`, `rsv`, `opcode` and `mask` are written right after the table you excerpted from RFC 6455.

`Payload Data` is a byte array. It is application-specific data.

The table represents the structure of one ***frame***. A ***message*** consists of either one frame or multiple frames.